# WordPress AddThis Facebook og:title meta tag

Tags: wordpress, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

How do I override the WordPress Facebook "og:title" content="(no title)" meta tag for an AddThis FB share button?

I added the meta tag:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="The Modern Rapunzel" />
```

to the child-theme header.php, but it's displaying "(no title)" in the FB share popup when I click on the AddThis button.

Running the Facebook debugger shows both meta tags are in there somewhere:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="The Modern Rapunzel" />
```

and

```
<meta property="og:title" content="(no title)" />
```

No idea where it's pulling that second one from; it's not defined in header.php

Comment: you need to put hook for this.